# Create Pandas DataFrame from dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I was trying to convert a dictionary of `{'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5]}` into:

```
 0           | 1           | 
|:-----------|------------:| 
| a          |        1    |  
| a          |        2    |   
| a          |        3    |     
| b          |        4    |    
| b          |        5    |
```

But haven't found any way to achieve that without modifying the dictionary itself. Is there an easier way to do that? Any help will be really appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `pd.DataFrame.from_dict`

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d,'index').stack().reset_index(level=0)
Out[194]: 
  level_0    0
0       a  1.0
1       a  2.0
2       a  3.0
0       b  4.0
1       b  5.0
```

Comment: Noooo, `stack` again :(

Comment: @jpp  I just try to using pandas function to answer the question, since pandas library have the stack . If we do care about the speed , I think numba and cpython should be considered here.

Comment: @Wen, Don't worry, I still think it's a great answer. But simplicity comes at a cost :(

Answer (score 6):

you can expand the dict into list of tuples and then convert into df as follows;

```
ddd = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5]}
df = pd.DataFrame([(k,v) for k in ddd for v in ddd[k]])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `numpy.concatenate` and `numpy.repeat`:

```
import numpy as np

d = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5]}

values = np.concatenate(list(d.values()))
lens = list(map(len, d.values()))

res = pd.DataFrame({0: np.repeat(list(d), lens),
                    1: values})
```

**Result**

```
   0  1
0  a  1
1  a  2
2  a  3
3  b  4
4  b  5
```

This seems tougher than it should be, but remember you need to create arrays for each series / column. In essence, we need to **repeat** dictionary keys for series `0` and **concatenate** dictionary values for series `1`.